# No funciona JQuery en un archivo js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap

Mi problema es que no puedo usar jquery en mis archivos js, apesar que ya esta integrado en html e incluso funciona con bootstrap.
Trate incluyendo JQuery antes y despues de los JS pero no se soluciono.

```js
class User {
  contructor(name,pass){
    this.name = name;
    this.pass = pass;
  }
  
  dis(){
    //$('.navbar').fadeOut();
  }
}


var u = new User();
u.dis();
$('.navbar').fadeOut();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <base href="http://localhost/FreedomWallpapers/" target="_blank">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title></title>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="views/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="views/app/css/hometemplate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
  </head>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-faded" >
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Freedom Wallpapers</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Categorias</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Perfil</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 mx-auto" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginFormModal">Login</button>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="loginFormModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Iniciar Sesion</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="logEmail" placeholder="Email">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="logPassword" placeholder="Password">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-check">
                          <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Recordarme
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success float-right" id="loginButton">Ingresar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning float-right mr-2" id="registerButton">Registrarse</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<script src="views/app/js/login.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <body>
    <section class="homeSection">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="welcomeText">
          <h2>Freedom Wallpapers</h2>
          <h5>El mejor sitio para descargar wallpapers.</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="randomSection bg-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="text-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p class="text-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="views/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quita esto

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-
A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

y reemplazalo por esto:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ademas de Cambiar el Jquery también mueve tus archivos js que necesite Jquery justo después de la inclusión de jquery, así tendrás el valor de $ existente de lo contrario igual tendrás problemas.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="views/app/js/login.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

puedes usar la versión 3 estable pero ten cuidado con algunos navegadores y librerías que quieras usar adicionales pudieran no funcionarte, en ese caso te recomiendo usar la versión 2